# How to merge single-column pandas data frames in Python?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I want to merge the dataset into a 1432 rows x 4 columns data frame. After I used for loop function to filter the all data, the output was separated into 4 outputs, each 1432 rows x 1 column. However, I want them to merge into one table. How I can merge them?

My code and its output:

```
for ind,row in gf.iterrows():
    filter2 = savgol_filter(row, 31,3)
    hf = pd.DataFrame(filter2)
    hf.to_numpy()
  
    print(hf)
```

Output:

```
             0
0     0.901141
1     0.915138
2     0.928173
3     0.940281
4     0.951494
...        ...
1427  0.108484
1428  0.111043
1429  0.113958
1430  0.117230
1431  0.120859

[1432 rows x 1 columns]
             0
0     0.926357
1     0.940313
2     0.953292
3     0.965326
4     0.976451
...        ...
1427  0.108484
1428  0.111043
1429  0.113958
1430  0.117230
1431  0.120859

[1432 rows x 1 columns]
             0
0     0.926577
1     0.941009
2     0.954399
3     0.966784
4     0.978202
...        ...
1427  0.108484
1428  0.111043
1429  0.113958
1430  0.117230
1431  0.120859

[1432 rows x 1 columns]
             0
0     0.928050
1     0.942212
2     0.955387
3     0.967608
4     0.978907
...        ...
1427  0.108484
1428  0.111043
1429  0.113958
1430  0.117230
1431  0.120859
```

Comment: @OCa Hi, the output of dataframe is similar with array. There are 4 dataframe sets separately.

Comment: @OCa 1432 rows x 1 column with 4 sets in gf but I want them to 1 set like 1432 rows x 4 columns in 1 set.

Comment: @OCa I coded following your suggestion, the out put shows 1432 rows x 4columns but they are 4 sets and each set has the same values in each columns. For filter2, I have the noisy data 4 sets at the first my dataframe is 4rowsx1432 columns. I need to smooth it by using savgol_filter for loop so it can smooth 4 samples in one time. Could you have any suggestion to merge them in one set?

Comment: @OCa I coded like this, now it can merge the all columns into noe dataset. However, It is still has 4 datasets with the same value. But it is more promising. for ind,row in gf.iterrows():
     y=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(savgol_filter(row, 31, 3)) for (ind, row) in gf.iterrows()],axis=1)
     display(y)

Comment: When I remove the loop the error displayed like this     y=pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(savgol_filter(row, 31, 3)) for (ind, row) in gf.iterrows()],axis=1)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of knowledge of what `savgol_filter()` does, reformulating your for loop into a [*comprehension*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) may be the best guess:

```
hf = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(savgol_filter(row, 31, 3)) for (ind, row) in gf.iterrows()], axis=1)
```

Alternatively:

```
hf = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(savgol_filter(df.iloc[ix], 31, 3)) for ix in gf.index], axis=1)
```

**Enforcing index `ind` to land as column name:**

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(columns = [ind],
                        data = row) for (ind, row) in df.iterrows()], axis=1)
```

#### Explanation

There are several flaws in your loop design:

- Your `for` loop assigns a new data frame to the same variable at every iteration and this does not look like something you want to do. Instead, the *comprehension* processes all rows as a list, which lets you concatenate them as one object in the end.
- `.to_numpy` does not look useful, since you request a data frame as final product. It also is not assigned to a variable so it is without purpose a in the loop.

Depending on the nature of your `savgol_filter` function, simpler syntaxes may be possible.